# Forking tests fail because javaOptions seems to be misconfigured

Tags: jvm, sbt, playframework-2.2, fork, permgen

Using Play 2.X, I expect my tests to be forked by default (new way from Play 2.X) and especially well run.

However, when using this SBT configuration in my `Build.scala`, I observe an OOM due to permgen space, like the following:

```
Uncaught exception when running myspecs.AllSpecs: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at scala.collection.parallel.immutable.LazyParVectorCombiner.result(ParVector.scala:129)
    at scala.collection.parallel.immutable.LazyParVectorCombiner.result(ParVector.scala:105)
    at scala.collection.Parallelizable$class.par(Parallelizable.scala:42)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.par(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.specs2.reporter.AllExporting$$anonfun$export$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AllExporting.scala:28)
    at org.specs2.reporter.AllExporting$$anonfun$export$1$$anonfun$2.apply(AllExporting.scala:27)
    at scalaz.syntax.IdOps$class.$bar$greater(IdOps.scala:15)
    at scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps$$anon$1.$bar$greater(IdOps.scala:82)
    at org.specs2.reporter.AllExporting$$anonfun$export$1.apply(AllExporting.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.reporter.AllExporting$$anonfun$export$1.apply(AllExporting.scala:24)
    at scalaz.syntax.IdOps$class.$bar$greater(IdOps.scala:15)
    at scalaz.syntax.ToIdOps$$anon$1.$bar$greater(IdOps.scala:82)
    at org.specs2.reporter.AllExporting$class.report(AllExporting.scala:17)
    at org.specs2.reporter.SbtConsoleReporter.report(SbtReporter.scala:20)
    at org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner.org$specs2$runner$SbtRunner$$specificationRun(SbtRunner.scala:75)
    at org.specs2.runner.SbtRunner$$anonfun$newTask$1$$anon$5.execute(SbtRunner.scala:59)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.runTest(ForkMain.java:239)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.runTestSafe(ForkMain.java:211)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.runTests(ForkMain.java:187)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.run(ForkMain.java:251)
```

My configuration is the following:
 - My `ApplicationBuild.scala` is present [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9672fb9cfe0dbe41992b)
 - My plugins.sbt is present [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46f4f59b7c64179c2d3b)
 - My build.properties is present [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e8a4a0b3ac2d0f899a6)

But if I just change this line:

```
javaOptions in (Test,run) ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

by this line:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

**the whole works.**

**Why specifying `(Test, run)` make the whole fail?**

Am I missing some specified tasks other than `Test` and `run`?

I really would like to well figure it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cofiguration

```
javaOptions in (Test,run) ++= Seq(...)
```

says configuration Test and for key run, but running the tests are not done with the key run, it is done with the key test, so you have defined the setting for something else than running the tests

```
javaOptions in (Test,test) ++= Seq(...)
```

or just

```
javaOptions in (Test) ++= Seq(...)
```

should get you there!